# avoid resolving dependencies on each code change

Tags: compilation, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm developing with Play 2.1.1-RC1 in **~run** mode.

Is there a way to avoid checking of all the dependencies each time I update my classes?

For example excluding *org.hibernate.javax.persistence*, *be.objectify.deadbolt-core* and others would cut compilation time from 14 to 3 secs for me.

**ADDITION:**

I've found that it's possible to add "**offline := true**" to Build.scala and plugins.sbt. With this option it stops resolving from remote repos, but still it takes around 10 secons to resolve from local one. I'm looking for a way to disable resolving completely. My goal is to minimize compilation time as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `run` instead of `~run`.

Check out the play console instructions: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/PlayConsole

Comment: run works the same way as ~run for me. It does not trigger compilation on file change but still compiles with resolving from all the repos. Should it act differently?